# What type of pin header is this?

Tags: arduino-uno, pins, breadboard

Most of the Arduino uno boards have black female pin header. when i bought a ardiuno uno the digital pins 0 to 7 are made of silver pins. What type of pin  header is that? How to use these kind of pin headers?

[image: The image shows an adruino uno r3. with some silver pin headers]

Comment: it is just the black plastic removed

Comment: What makes them basically unusable. You should remove them and solder on a new one

Comment: if you do not want to do any soldering, then you may be able to push on another shell ... you could also put heat shrink tubing on each of those forks

Answer (score 3):

These are corrupted female headers so remove them and solder new ones.